# Производительность webclient и httpClient c#

Tags: c#, .net, производительность

[image: вот какое дело]

Всем привет,  пишу небольшую программку на с#
Столкнулся с невероятно низкой производительностью webclient и httpClient(20-30 секунд на запрос до Гугла, хотя при трассировке через cmd было всё норм)
Через несколько дней мучений обнаружил, что стоит отключить hamachi в сетевых адаптерах(сам hamachi выключен при этом), сразу запросы отлично работают.

Но через несколько секунд адаптер самостоятельно включается. Сносить hamachi не хочу, та и юзер(абстрактный, само собой, кому мой мусор нужен) вряд-ли этим займётся.

Можно как-то явно задать адаптер, которым программа будет пользоваться, игнорируя другие?
Proxy менял как на null, так и на defaultProxy

Comment: HttpClient создаешь на каждый новый запрос или кэшируешь его?

Comment: Создаю новый, но пока адаптер хамачи включён все запросы очень долгие, выключаю - сразу летают

Comment: Не воспроизводится однако, тоже использую хамачи от случая к случаю плюс виртуальные адаптеры от VPN и Hyper-V висят активными почти всегда, но такой проблемы не имею. Может какие настройки маршрутизации или адаптеров мешают? Короче смотреть надо куда и как пакеты летают на вашей машине при запросах, иначе никак =(

Comment: Трассировал в cmd, всё отлично работает, путь одинаковый

Comment: Можно посмотреть, как ты воспроизводил?

Comment: Вобщем попросил друга потестить(у него совершенно другие конфигурация системы, роутер, провайдер и место жительства). Проблема спокойно воспроизвелась(тоже юзает хамачи)